# EXTJS - AJAX - redirect to URL without using location.href

Tags: javascript, extjs4

In my code,  I have to redirect to a vendors SSO page  via location.href …problem is that I cannot tell if the redirect was successful or not due to no callbacks in location.href.

So, I choose to use AJAX GET instead,  based on a 200 or a 401 response I know if the SSO process worked or not.

However,  I cannot seem to figure out how to get the success handler to redirect the page to the sso url based on the 200 response.

Is there any way to invoke the redirect based on the successful response object ?

I do not even know if this is possible or what the best approach should be?

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url:sso_url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (resp, ops) {

        //on a 200 how do I redirect without using location.href: sso_url 

        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
  });
```

Comment: So you want to redirect to the same page that is also your login page...?

Comment: Its a redirect to a vendors login page...the sso_url will return a 200 or a 401, on a 200  I would want to redirect to the url otherwise tell the user that SSO authentication failed.

Comment: Isn't this usually handled by a cookie or some sort of session that's returned from the successful log in?  So if you received a cookie or session, then the redirect would be fine, as you'd code to check for that item.  Other than that, I'm unclear as to what you are asking, which is probably why you were downvoted.

Comment: Thanks Incutonez for the sanity check, unfortunately I am not able to use the cookie or the session created against the successful 200 AJAX call.

Comment: Any reason why?  Maybe I'm not understanding the problem completely, but perhaps you could try utilizing the [History util](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.History) somehow?

Comment: Its an external SSO site and a single sign on.

Comment: My research tells me that ajax does not support redirects, JS simulates redirect via location. or window.   hanks for your help

Comment: incutonez, thanks for your input, helped me to bounce a few ideas around,I figured out a solution, added it below.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of more help.  Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by opening a window and writing out the responseText from my API.

This might not work for everyone but it worked for my purposes.

```
success: function (data, status) {
        var myWindow = window.open("", "_self");
        myWindow.document.write(resp.responseText);
});
```